# Как с помощью telethon получить file_id файла для ботов?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

Мне надо получить file_id файла через telethon из обычного сообщения из паблик-канала, чтобы потом отправить этот файл через бота.
Знаю, что есть метод telethon.utils.pack_bot_file_id(), но когда я его вызываю, вылетает ошибка

```
AttributeError: 'PhotoSize' object has no attribute 'location'
```

Вызываю так:

```py
msgs = client.get_messages(channel['source_channel'],
                           min_id=channel['last_msg_id'],
                           limit=None
                           )
file_id = telethon.utils.pack_bot_file_id(msgs[0].photo)
```

Comment: Покажите всю функцию, что происходит до объявления переменной file_id

Comment: @MyZik добавил выше